# How To Make Cisco Switch Pingable Behind Another Non-Cisco Switch

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, snmp

**The Problem:** I have plugged a cisco switch into a non-cisco switch for testing purposes and cannot ping it. I cannot touch the non-cisco switch other than to plug something into it. The switch cannot ping its default gateway, and no machine in the subnet/vlan can ping the switch.

**Background Info:** The non-cisco switch is configured to serve frames on VLAN 24. There is a layer 3 subnet that corresponds to this VLAN that looks like 10.0.24.0/24.

**What I've Attempted:** Here is the output of my configuration.

```
Test#show running-config interface fastethernet 0/1
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 84 bytes
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 24
 switchport mode access
end


Test#show running-config
.
. omitted 
.
interface Vlan24
 ip address 10.0.24.234 255.255.255.0
!         
ip default-gateway 10.0.24.1
.
. omitted
.
snmp-server community public-ro RO
.
. omitted
.
```

**Why I'm Doing This:** I'm trying to write a script to enable snmp on any cisco switch in a test environment.

Comment: What model Cisco switch?  Is IP routing otherwise enabled on the switch?

Comment: Have you checked if the non-Cisco switch port is configured as a tagged or untagged VLAN?

Comment: Also it's more common to use `switchport mode trunk` for switch to switch connection.

Comment: If you want one switch to pass traffic for a VLAN on a separate switch you should configure the uplink to be a trunk port.

Answer (score 1):

If there is just single VLAN assigned to the port (non-tagging) on the non-cisco switch I'd suggest to modify the setting like:

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport trunk native vlan 24
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 24
end
```

I'm writing it without access to any Cisco switch from home so there can be something missing...